# Can alias column used in a view for calculation in some other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.myview1 As
SELECT 
a.Id , 
a.Name , 
a.Age , 
CASE 
WHEN b.PmtSched ='Monthly'      THEN 12
WHEN b.PmtSched ='Quarterly'    THEN 4
WHEN b.PmtSched ='Semi-Annual'  THEN 2
WHEN b.PmtSched ='Annually'     THEN 1
ELSE 12
END AS ABC,
SUM(a.Amount) *50 as TotalAmount ,
(a.AmtSpent - TotalAmount) * ABC as TOTALSPENDS 

FROM dbo.User a join dbo.Details b on a.Id = b.Id
```

Here ABC and TotalAmount are Alias columns which needs to be used in computation in view and i am not able to use them.how to achieve this ?is there any way we could do this or we cant ?please help.

Comment: No, it cannot be.  You can use a subquery or CTE instead.  This is true of all databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it and you don't need neither subqueries, nor CTEs. It's a simple [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It's quite elegant and doesn't hurt readability. If you need more information, read [here](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases).

Please see this example:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.myview1
AS
SELECT A.Id
    , A.Name
    , A.Age
    , SUM(A.Amount) * 50 AS TotalAmount
    , (A.AmtSpent - TotalAmount) * T.ABC AS TotalSpends
FROM dbo.[User] AS A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE B.PmtSched
            WHEN 'Monthly' THEN 12
            WHEN 'Quarterly' THEN 4
            WHEN 'Semi-Annual' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Annually' THEN 1
            ELSE 12
        END) AS T(ABC)
INNER JOIN dbo.Details AS B
    ON A.Id = B.Id;
```

Comment: Depends on your perspective, I suppose. What would you describe the contents of the parenthesis after the `APPLY` as, if not a subquery?

Comment: I guess it's a matter of perspective and argument. Quick Googling tells me that *These subqueries can reside in the WHERE clause, the FROM clause, or the SELECT clause*. I was basing my question on that. But good spot. Thank you. [Source](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/subqueries.php)

Comment: This helped.Thanks @Evaldas Buinauskas

Answer (score 5):

The simple solution to your problem is to repeat the expression, use a subquery, or use a CTE.

However, the more intelligent method is to add a reference table for payment schedules.  This would look like:

```
create table PaymentSchedules (
    PaymentScheduleId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    ScheduleName varchar(255),
    FrequencyPerYear float  -- this could be less often than once per year
);
```

Then the view would look like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.myview1 As
    SELECT a.Id, a.Name, a.Age, ps.FrequencyPerYear, 
           SUM(a.Amount) * 50 as TotalAmount,
           (a.AmtSpent - SUM(a.Amount) * 50) * ps.FrequencyPerYear as TOTALSPENDS 
    FROM dbo.User a join
         dbo.Details b
         on a.Id = b.Id join
         dbo.PaymentSchedules ps
         on ps.PaymentScheduleId = a.PamentScheduleId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer **"NO"**

It's impossible to do this without a [subquery](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm).

*or*

You need to use [CTE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275645/CTE-In-SQL-Server)

> Below query will help you to get what you need.

```
;WITH Amount
(
SELECT a.Id,a.NAME,a.Age,a.AmtSpent,
            CASE WHEN b.PmtSched ='Monthly'      THEN 12
                 WHEN b.PmtSched ='Quarterly'    THEN 4
                 WHEN b.PmtSched ='Semi-Annual'  THEN 2
                 WHEN b.PmtSched ='Annually'     THEN 1
            ELSE 12
            END AS ABC
           ,SUM(a.Amount) * 50 AS TotalAmount
    FROM 
        dbo.[User] a
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Details b ON a.Id = b.Id
    GROUP BY id, NAME, age, abc, a.AmtSpent, TotalAmount
)
```

> Now you can call those alias for calculation.

```
SELECT id,NAME,age,abc,(a.AmtSpent - TotalAmount) * ABC AS TOTALSPENDS FROM Amount
```